# How to increase a number by x% in Sqldeveloper

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm new to sqldeveloper and don't understand how to update a number (that is in a table) by for example 5%.

I tried this:

```
update column_name set (number = number *1.05);
```

thanks in advance for telling me the answer,

Ramon

Comment: When something doesn't work, you should always tell us what happens. (In your case you probably got an error message, you should have shown.)

Comment: In order to "to update *a* number (that is in a table)" you would have to specify which column *and* which row. Or do you want to update the values in all records?

Answer (score 1):

You were close, you just seemed to be missing the table name after the [`UPDATE`](http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/update.php) statement and then your query should work as expected as the general syntax for updating is as follows:

```
UPDATE YourTable 
   SET YourColumn = YourPreferredValue
```

So if your column being targeted was actually `number` and you wanted to increase it by 105%, then you could use :

```
UPDATE YourTable 
   SET number = number * 1.05
```

Comment: It's hard to be sure from the question, but shouldn't `number` be `column_name`? I *think* the OP was misusing the data type, rather than masking the name of the column, but either way it would be a little clearer with a legal name.

Comment: It is rather ambiguous and I assumed `number` was the column name. I'll provide a generic query and then one that might use the information OP provided.

Comment: im sorry about the bad question, heres a better  example: my table is called example, my column is called number and i only want to append certain rows where my column = 'salesman''.

Comment: i got the error: "missing right parenthesis" although i did exactly what @Rion Williams said...

Comment: nevermind it actually worked now, forgot columnentries were case sensitive